Using builds created as part of pull request can be promoted to production
We have few applications creating build artifacts as part of, if someone creating pull request against main branch and the same build artifact used all the way to move into production. But some other applications we follow a pattern, always build from release branch after the PR gets merged. I believe the later is right approach considering PRs are proposal and we should not create something based on proposal rather than a commit. Thoughts? and please share the pros and cons of either approach?
